# Two conflicting responses to Outlook message recall

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I recall an Outlook message, I get two responses. One says the recall was successful, while the other says it failed.

Why is this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Hello Fem875. Please give as many helpful information as you can. What OS and what Outlook version are you using. Are there any exchange server involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recall message only works when the user accepts or rejects the recall. And you will get a success or fail response accordingly.

Comment: I am getting TWO responces, One says the recall was successful, they other says it was unsuccessful. Any Idea why that might happen?

Comment: Are you talking about 2 responses about the same email you sent?

Comment: Yes both responces are about the same message recall.

Comment: Running Win XP, Outlook 2007, exchange enterprise server.